# Connecting a USB device via an isolated hub fails

Tags: usb, debian, usb-hub

I'm trying to connect various sensitive equipment to my laptop using an isolated hub based on [ADuM3160](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM3160.pdf) converter chip. Most of the devices work just fine, but a few fail with errors I've never seen before:

> [ 2448.901481] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
>
> [ 2449.041811] usb 1-3: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
>
> [ 2449.042542] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=21a9, idProduct=1001
>
> [ 2449.042560] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
>
> [ 2449.197478] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 22
>
> [ 2450.973425] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
>
> [ 2451.113936] usb 1-3: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
>
> [ 2451.114410] usb 1-3: **config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 has 4 endpoint descriptors, different from the interface descriptor's value: 3**
>
> [ 2451.115198] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=21a9, idProduct=1001
>
> [ 2451.115215] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>
> [ 2451.115227] usb 1-3: Product: Logic S/16
>
> [ 2451.115236] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Saleae LLC

Can anyone shed some light on what might be the problem here? I've already ruled out the power issue by powering the isolated side of the hub through an external power supply which provides far more power than a logic analyzer may require (which is about 150mA @ 5V).

I also have a Windows 10 where my setup fails with similar symptoms (but without any useful diagnostics, the app just says "Please unplug and reconnect your device"), so if anyone has Windows-specific ideas I could test, I'm willing to try them out.

Comment: Is your "an isolated hub based on ADuM3160 chip" USB-IF certified? Does your device "idVendor=21a9" function correctly behind a normal (non-isolated) hub? In the very same system host I mean...

Comment: @AliChen The device works fine behind a hub. No USB-IF logo I'm afraid (now that you mention it, none of the Adafruit's USB products seem to be certified).

Comment: The AD de-coupler is good for FS only. Therefore the hub must be FS-only. When you say "works fine behind a hub", it likely means "behind USB 2.0 HS hub", because it is really hard to find an old-fashion FS USB 1.1 hub. Working behind a HS hub and through FS hub employs different softwares, since in FS case the transactions are handled by native UHCI controller, while FS devices behind a HS hub must use entirely different "split transactions". Try to find a FS hub. I bet the Saleae (clone?) will fail as well behind a FS hub.

Comment: @AliChen Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to find a FS hub to test. I have a dozen of USB HS devices (oscilloscopes, logic analysers, programmers and debuggers) which all worked via ADuM3160 with no hiccups (at a slower data rate obviously), only this one is being difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Product [support site](https://support.saleae.com/hc/en-us/articles/210244983-Can-the-Saleae-devices-operate-over-USB-Full-speed-as-when-used-with-a-full-speed-USB-isolator-) has the answer to this one:

> Only the original Logic currently works over USB 2.0/USB 1.1 Full speed. All other products will not operate properly.

Obviously, `Logic S/16` is not supported over a Full Speed connection.